# How to set "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" in Apps Script

Tags: javascript

In DriveApp File class there is the method
setShareableByEditors(shareable) which sets the "Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people"

but there does not seem to be a similar method for setting  "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers"

Is there a method to do this or some other way.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I think OP is asking about Google Drive, but I'm unsure since the question contains so little information.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) and set a restricted label. Something like this but haven't tested:

```
  var labels = {
    'labels': {restricted: true}
  };
  Drive.Files.update(labels, fileId);
```

In order to use the Advanced Drive Service, you must enabled it by going to Resources / Advanced Google services / and turning on Drive. This must be also be enabled in the [api console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis).

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. Was extra apostrophe  in {restricted': true} corrected syntax is. var labels = {
    'labels': {restricted: true}
  };
  Drive.Files.update(labels, fileId);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, worked fine. Was extra apostrophe in {restricted': true} corrected syntax is. var labels = { 'labels': {restricted: true} }; Drive.Files.update(labels, fileId);

It would be good if the reference/guides covered this - I tried hard but could not find it.